# Экпроприаторша

Tags: заимствования, общие-вопросы

Захотел посмотреть фильм и натолкнулся на такое описание:

> Девушка Пиксила Шасс, ведущая разгульный образ жизни, имеет аристократичных и богатых родителей. Они ставят ей условие – или она идет работать, или не получит никакого наследства. Немного побузив, девушка устраивается работать в «Вельветовую Перчатку» **экспроприаторшей** и неожиданно попадает в центр необыкновенной истории, связанной с пропавшим поездом.

Интересует какую профессию могли так обозвать. Смотреть только из-за этого фильм, право нет никакого желание, но интересно какую всё-таки профессию могли так перевести. Фильм, в оригинале "Repo Chick", тоже называется "Экспроприаторша".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта контора - что-то вроде наших коллекторов, вышибающих деньги из неплательщиков.Экспроприаторы должны возвращать купленные в рассрочку автомобили, если покупатели прекращают выплачивать за них деньги, часто они с бандитскими замашками, поэтому слово воспринимается синонимичным к "грабительница".

Answer (score 2):

Согласен с Людмилой. Я смотрел штатовский документальный сериал о таких экспроприаторах. Там команда из трёх человек экспроприировала купленные в рассрочку автомобили и бытовую технику у людей, которые вовремя не расплатились за покупку. Практически всегда этой команде приходилось отражать агрессию (чаще словесную) неплательщиков и в допустимых пределах применять физическую силу.

Answer (score 1):

ЭКСПРОПРИАЦИЯ, -и; ж. [франц. expropriation от лат. ex - из и proprius - собственный]
1. Юрид. В гражданском праве:
принудительное (безвозмездное или оплачиваемое)
отчуждение (изъятие) имущества, производимое государственными органами.
2. Книжн.
Вообще принудительное изъятие чего-л., лишение собственности. Э. экспроприаторов
(лишение буржуазии всех средств производства в ходе пролетарской революции). 
ЭКСПРОПРИАТОР, -а; м. Книжн.
Тот, кто совершает экспроприацию (2 зн.)

Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.

Экспроприаторша — ЭКСПРОПРИАТОР, а, м. (книжн.). Лицо, к рое экспроприирует кого что н. Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949 1992

Comment: @Серж, я тоже умею пользоваться словарями. По-вашему приведённые вами значения можно подставить к описанию фильма? И что тогда может экспроприировать организация "Вельветовая перчатка"?

Comment: Да, согласен с Людмилой.Да и в словарях синонимов даются такие значения, как: грабительница, воровка,  обирательница, бандитка, и т.д.